# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $ error

Tags: android, kotlin, post, request, retrofit2

I know there are some other topics on this problem but I couldn't find the solution for my error so if you have any suggestions, please let me know. I'm trying to create a POST request with a param in the body to retrieve some data from the API.

**My DataApi interface:**

```
interface ChartsDataApi {

@POST(NetworkUtils.CASH_COLLECTION_URL)
fun getCashCollection(@Body guid: String) : Call<List<CashCollection>>

@POST(NetworkUtils.TICKETS_DETAILS_URL)
fun getTicketsDetails() : Call<List<TicketDetails>>
```

}

**My fun where I'm using Retrofit and where I'm trying to get the response:**

```
private fun geCashCollectionDetails(){
    var params : MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
    val BASE_URL = " here i wrote the base URL "
    val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create()
   val api = Retrofit.Builder()
           .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
           .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
           .build()
           .create(ChartsDataApi::class.java)

    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
        val response = api.getCashCollection(" **here i wrote the guid** ").awaitResponse()
        if(response.isSuccessful){
            val day = response.body()!!.lastIndex
            Log.d("RAZZ", day.toString())
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
            }
        }
    }
```

**My Data Class for CashCollection:**

```
data class CashCollection(
    @SerializedName("label")
    val label: String?,
    @SerializedName("value")
    val value: String?)
```

**Response from the server:**
*{"data":[{"label":"12.10.2020","value":"0,00"},{"label":"16.10.2020","value":"0,00"},{"label":"17.10.2020","value":"0,00"},{"label":"18.10.2020","value":"0,00"}],"currency":"EUR"}*

```
Process: com.eschbachit.citylinemobile, PID: 32529
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:174)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:215)
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37) 
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25) 
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243) 
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:174) 
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
```

When I'm trying to test and check the data I'm receiving, I get that error.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your data classes and response from server. This error means data from server can't be mapped into data classes that you provide as result of those requests.

Ok, data class must exactly reflect the structure of the response. Your `CashCollection` class must be

```kotlin
data class CashCollection(
    val data: ArrayList<CashCollectionItem>,
    val currency: String
) {
   data class CashCollectionItem(
       @SerializedName("label")
       val label: String?,
       @SerializedName("value")
       val value: String?)
}
```

and type of response `Call<CashCollection>`

Comment: Please check the question again, I added the Data Clasa and the response. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still getting the same error even if I modified that class..

Comment: Can you share full code of project. In GitHub for example

Comment: The project is very complex and I think it won't help you if you see the full code

Comment: Maybe the problem is how I'm trying to send the body param? @Maxim

Comment: Did you fix the return type in the network request?

Comment: You mean this? fun getCashCollection(@Body guid: String) : Call<CashCollection>

Comment: Yes. 
Please, tell me where this error is occurs. Or provide full stack trace of it

Comment: I think something is wrong with the body param. I have to send the param  **guid : 12345 ** (for example)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have incorrectly mapped your api response to kotlin classes. In your Retrofit api you say you expect the api to return a list of CashCollections (`[{"label":"12.12.1212", "value": ""0,00}]`), but the server returns a json object where that array is in the data property: `{"data":[{"label":"12.12.1212", "value": "0,00"}]}`

You should update your retrofit interface to correspond to what the api returns:

```
class CashCollectionResponse(
  @SerializedName("data") data: List<CashCollection>
)

interface ChartsDataApi {
  @POST("GetTheData")
  fun getCashCollection(@Body guid: String): Call<CashCollectionResponse>
}
```

Comment: I added @SerializedName("data") in my data class but I'm still getting the same error..

Comment: In what data class did you add the `@SerializedName("data")`? Because you should create an entire new data class which wraps the data, you shouldn't add it to the CashCollection data class.

Comment: Also, maybe the issue is not in the response, but in the request, as you've stated. I advise you to read this: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-send-plain-text-request-body. So either define the body as a RequestBody, or use a scalars converterfactory

Comment: I added this line in the interface ChartsDataApi  @Headers("{Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8}") and this solved that problem. But now I'm getting as response "Bad Request"..